# In Star Wars, are protocol droids like C-3PO water-resistant?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, c-3po

As part of an upcoming change of scenery in a Star Wars (legends) RPG, our party, including a 3PO-series droid are off to a planet covered almost entirely in water. It's fairly relaxed, but we like to stick to the given knowledge of the Star Wars galaxy where possible.

In Empire Strikes Back, we see that R2-D2 can function underwater, even if he does get a little waterlogged, but I can't assume that C-3PO (for example) would fare similarly.

My question is; could protocol droids like C-3PO survive being submerged in water? Are there examples of this happening in novels, TV shows etc. I might have missed? I'm happy to take Canon answers if there is nothing in Legends.

Comment: Considering the design probably not if he existed in our world but in the _Star Wars_ universe it could go either way.

Comment: we've seen him several times in snowy terrain in canon (tv / film) - reasonably, some of the snow would get into the exposed areas of his body and melt - granted, that's not quite equivalent to submersion but...

Comment: Given you have an example of a droid functioning fine after being submerged and no examples of droids ceasing to function due to water occam's razor suggests it would be fine to assume that all droids are water resistant.

Comment: @Chris - Extrapolating a trend from a single point of data is a whole different fallacy

Comment: Well, we saw C-3P0 being partially submerged into an oil bath, and saying it would do him good. The oil was able to make it past his outer casing, and did not cause him to malfunction or shut down. This suggests that his circuitry is resistant to liquid, no?

Comment: @VBartilucci - There's a huge difference between submerging an electrical device into oil (https://youtu.be/ThUEwlmSeV4?t=245) and into water (https://youtu.be/7D7aUFMozOc?t=118)

Comment: @Valorum: My point is that if its your only data point that is the sensible extrapolation to make.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a (Legends) reference in [Legacy of the Force IX: Invincible](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Invincible) to a protocol droid happily walking through wind and rain. Obviously this isn't the same as waterproof, but it does imply water-*resistance*

> Kell stared out into the darkness, noted the clustered pinpoints of
>   red light that floated in the pitch. He shifted on his feet as the
>   lights drew closer—a silver protocol droid. He attuned his vision to
>   Fate, saw no daen nosi. Droids were programming, nothing more. They
>   made no real choices and so had no lines. The false sentience of the
>   droid unnerved Kell and he cut off the perception.
>
> **The anthropomorphic droid strode through the wind and rain to the base
>   of the landing ramp and bowed its head in a hum of servos.**
>
> “Master Anzat,” the droid said in Basic. “I am Deefourfive. Please
>   follow me. The Master awaits you.”

and again, in [The New Jedi Order: Force Heretic II: Refugee](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Force_Heretic_II:_Refugee). Note that Threepio seems entirely unfazed even when the rain comes down in "great sheets".

> Han and Jaina also turned to look at C-3PO now. As if in response to
>   the droid’s words, a peal of thunder rumbled from the tropical sky.
>   **Fat raindrops began to splatter his metal cranium, turning what dust
>   was there to a reddish mud. “Threepio, are you sure about this?” Leia
>   asked.**
>
> ...
>
> **Rain began to fall in great sheets across the stadium** as the sides of
>   the troopships opened, issuing ramps. Jaina squinted to see through
>   the rain, trying to make out what lay inside.

And in the 1983 Marvel comic story [Ellie (Star Wars #80)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_80:_Ellie) C-3PO is seen standing in rain.

[image]

Comment: I think I recall the context of those frames, and can hear him repeating the words "We seem to be made to suffer. It's our lot in life". The fact they can tolerate heavy rain is promising, we might send him for a swim yet!

Comment: As there might never have been an example of poor 3PO going for a swim (we humoured he'd sink like a rock), we're going with this as a good indication that they might work underwater, but we won't actively encourage them to do so!

Comment: @Kozaky - He'd definitely sink, if the fact that he sinks in oil is anything to go by